# Return Http Status (eg. 401) or redirect Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I use this configuration to `Spring Security`:

```
   <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </session-management>

        <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"  authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>
```

I need to return an `Http Error Code` like `401` if the `Content-Type` in my header's request is: `application/json;` otherwise I want to redirect to Login Page.

But with this configuration, regardless of request content type I'm being redirected to login url with a `302` response code..

Is there a way to do this??

**EDIT:**
I want use only one servlet to handler the html and json so I try this:

```
@Component
public class CustomEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomEntryPoint.class);

        public CustomEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
            super(loginFormUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            if(request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().equals("application/json")) {
                 response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access Denied");
            }else {
                super.commence(request, response, authException);
            }

        }
    }
```

And this is my new Security Configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint">
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>

    <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"  authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customEntryPoint" class="x.x.CustomEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/login"/>
</beans:bean>
```

What do you think about that? It is a correct way to do it, or do you know a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
public class CustomEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final String XML_HTTP_REQUEST = "XMLHttpRequest";
    private static final String X_REQUESTED_WITH = "X-Requested-With";

    public CustomEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (XML_HTTP_REQUEST.equals(request.getHeader(X_REQUESTED_WITH))) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
            super.commence(request, response, exception);
        }
    }

}
```

And Security configuration is:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint">
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>

    <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"  authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customEntryPoint" class="x.x.CustomEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/login"/>
</beans:bean>
```